# JQuery sorting DIV by content

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am using the following code to sort DIV content by date and title.

It works well, but for date I want to sort it with newest first - at the moment it puts the newest last.

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
    var vA = jQuery(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = jQuery(keySelector, b).text();
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
});
parent.append(items);
}

/* setup sort attributes */
jQuery('#sDate').data("sortKey", "span.date");
jQuery('#sStyle').data("sortKey", "span.title");


/* sort on button click */
jQuery("button.btnSort").click(function() {
sortUsingNestedText(jQuery('.sort-div'), "div", 
jQuery(this).data("sortKey"));
});
```

How can I change the order for date only (#sPrice)

Comment: Share the relevant HTML

Comment: Just alternate 0 & 1.

Comment: But I want to keep the sort order for the title (#sStyle) - just change the sort order for the Date

Comment: Answer depends on how flexible it needs to be. Does it need to sort other types also ...or just do date type? Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Add a parser on the selector in a conditional in the sort callback.

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
  var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) { 

    var vA = jQuery(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = jQuery(keySelector, b).text();

    // date sorting
    if(keySelector.indexOf('.date') >-1){
       return new Date(vB) - new Date(vA);
    }else{
       return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    }
  });
  parent.append(items);
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work - the date has values stored as year only though - does that make a difference? (ie. 2017)

Comment: Well you ignored request to post a [mcve]. Just subtract them then